# Spring RESTful + hibernate multimodule project

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I need to create an application consisting of several modules:

- authorization (authorization module)
- main (main module)
- directories(module directories)
- logging module (logging)

In the future there may be other modules. Each module is a standalone **Restful Spring + hibernate** application (war file).

Modules should interact with each other. That is, for example, the main module uses the reference from the module directories.

The question is, what is the practice of interaction between such autonomous modules?

Answer (score 1):

This is a blog is for Webapp Inter-Communication in Tomcat:
https://blog.konstantinpavlov.net/2014/05/09/webapp-inter-communication-in-tomcat/

Answer (score 1):

Now if they were dependent modules,
it would have been a best practice to take out a common module that contains code common to each one of them and then have separate modules with the separate modules dependent on common module.

But as I understand from your problem, I think you need to make VOs that will help interact with different modules. VOs may be a sort of contract in inter-communication of modules.

Also since you are building your application in Rest, VOs(Value Objects) will let you communicate efficiently and easily.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in general: JMS is an option. 
There would be queues/topics on which producers would post messages and consumers who listens on the queues/topics will react on the messages. 
Synchronization between different modules or applications can be done very well using JMS.
JMS apis are explained here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html
Note that you would need a JMS provider (an implementation).

But that really depends on the application requirements, environment, etc.

And for me it is hard to understand to context you describe.